# Create a php array with keys and values from mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to store my mysql query in an array like this :

```
$arr = array ( "field1"=>"value" , "field2"=>"value" , "field3"=>"value" , ... );
```

I've tried this but don't work like I need :

```
$row_selectProduct = array();
$sResult = $db->query( 'SELECT * FROM tbl' )    

while ( $aRow = $sResult->fetch_assoc() )
{
        $sInfo = $sResult->fetch_field();
        // General output
        $row_selectProduct[ $sInfo->name ] = $aRow;
}

$sResult->close();
```

Thx for help

**EDIT :**
Sorry for misunderstanding...
I'd like to name keys by the field name in database.
I try to reproduce this :

```
$result = array();

while ($row_selectProduct = mysql_fetch_assoc($selectProduct));
{

    $row_array= array();

$row_array['field_name1_In_DB'] = $row_selectProduct['field_name1_In_DB'];
$row_array['field_name2_In_DB'] = $row_selectProduct['field_name2_In_DB'];
$row_array['field_name3_In_DB'] = $row_selectProduct['field_name3_In_DB'];
$row_array['field_name4_In_DB'] = $row_selectProduct['field_name4_In_DB'];
$row_array['field_name5_In_DB'] = $row_selectProduct['field_name5_In_DB'];
...

array_push($result,$row_array);

};
```

Comment: `don't work like i need` doesn't tell much. What's the current result?

Comment: Is that example supposed to be *one row* or *several rows*? Isn't `$aRow` already in the format you want?

Comment: @deceze SELECT * FROM tbl will definitly result in several rows

Comment: @MrSo If it's the current result - you've got what you want. What's the problem?

Comment: @steven Not if there's only one row. ;-P `$arr` Seems to be only one row though, so if that's the desired output the question makes no sense. Well, it doesn't either way.

Comment: I need entire results in one array. Sry for confusion. Question edited for more explanations

Comment: Think about it! Assigning all keys in an array to the exact same keys in another array... **that's the same as `$a = $b`.** `$aRow` is already in the format you want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while ( $aRow = $sResult->fetch_assoc() )
{
        foreach($aRow as $fieldname => $fieldvalue) {
             $row_selectProduct[$fieldname] = $fieldvalue;   
        }

}
```

but you will overwrite your $row_selectedProduct with every record and the var at the end will only have stored the last record

if you would like to have all results in one array you should:

```
$results = array();
while ( $aRow = $sResult->fetch_assoc() )
{
        $results[] = $aRow;

}
```

if you know that there will be only one result you need only:

```
$result = $sResult->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: The inner loop is completely superfluous.

Comment: `$rowSelectProduct[] = $aRow;`.. no need to waste a bunch of cpu cycles looping over the result row array when you can simply assign the entire array.

Comment: yes I know but i want to make it clear what would be the right syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Using [PDO connection functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), it's quite simple --

```
foreach($db->query('SELECT field_name1,field_name2 FROM table') as $row) {
    echo $row['field_name1'].' '.$row['field_name2']; //etc...
}
```

Here's a good [tutorial for PDO in PHP](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) if you want more.